# Group same elements in JS array, but only when consecutive

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I have an array of objects representing a series of 'messages' in a chat. I want to group messages that are consecutively created by the same 'user', which is stored in each array item. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
[
    { message: "One", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Two", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Three", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }
]
```

should be turned into:

```
[
    [
        { message: "One", user: "Bob"},
        { message: "Two", user: "Bob" },
        { message: "Three", user: "Bob" }
    ],
    [
        { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }
    ],
    [
        { message: "Hello", user: "Bob" }
    ],
    [
        { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" },
        { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }
    ]
]
```

Is there any easy way to do this? I couldn't find an answer/algorithm anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that with the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const data = [
  { message: "One", user: "Bob" },
  { message: "Two", user: "Bob" },
  { message: "Three", user: "Bob" },
  { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" },
  { message: "Hello", user: "Bob" },
  { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" },
  { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, value) => {
  // compare the current value with the last item in the collected array
  if (acc.length && acc[acc.length - 1][0].user == value.user) {
    // append the current value to it if it is matching
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(value);
  } else {
    // append the new value at the end of the collected array
    acc.push([value]);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```js
const messages = [
    { message: "One", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Two", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Three", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Bob" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" },
    { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }
]

let currentUser;
let groupedMessages = [];

for (message of messages) {

  if (message.user !== currentUser) {
    groupedMessages.push([]);
    currentUser = message.user;
  }
  groupedMessages[groupedMessages.length - 1].push(message)
}

console.log(groupedMessages);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the last element and if it has not the same user, then create a new array.

```js
var data = [{ message: "One", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Two", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Three", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
        if (!i || a[i - 1].user !== o.user) {
            r.push([]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with just [**`Array.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and using its parameters for `index` of the array and the `actual array`:

```js
const data = [{ message: "One", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Two", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Three", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Bob" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" }, { message: "Hello", user: "Sam" } ]

const group = d => d.reduce((r,c,i,a) => (a[i].user == (a[i-1] && a[i-1].user) 
 ? r[r.length-1].push(c) : r.push([c]), r), [])

console.log(Object.values(group(data)))
```