# How to group an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to group an array of objects. The array should be grouped following this quote:

> Group by `type` respecting the sequence.

**Array I wish to group**

```js
var arrayObj = [
    { "type": "user", "text": "user1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user2" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user3" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user4" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk2" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk3" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user5" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user6" }
];
```

**The way I want it to be grouped:**

```js
var newArray = [
  [
      {type: "user", text: "user1"},
      {type: "user", text: "user2"},
      {type: "user", text: "user3"}
  ],
  
  [
      {type: "clerk", text: "clerk1"}
  ],
  
  [
      {type: "user", text: "user4"}
  ],
  
  [
      {type: "clerk", text: "clerk2"},
      {type: "clerk", text: "clerk3"}
  ],  
    
  [
      {type: "user", text: "user5"},
      {type: "user", text: "user6"} 
  ]
];
```

**What i tried:**

I'm trying to use a filter, but without success since it even groups, but it groups all that are of the same type without respecting the sequence I want (from the array above);

```js
var arrayObj = [
    { "type": "user", "text": "user1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user2" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user3" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user4" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk2" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk3" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user5" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user6" }
];

var newArray = [];

newArray.push(filtrarArray(arrayObj, 'clerk'));
newArray.push(filtrarArray(arrayObj, 'user'));

console.log(newArray);

function filtrarArray(array, type) {
    return array.filter(function (val) {
        return val.type === type;
    });
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Group same elements in JS array, but only when consecutive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363702/group-same-elements-in-js-array-but-only-when-consecutive)

Comment: @pilchard actually, I just checked it out, and through this duplicate I tried to comment on my own question trying to summarize some of what I understood about a smaller code, and with better performance, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet below first sorts the array by type, which then makes it easy to loop through and group. Let me know if this solves your problem :)

**EDIT**

Just realized you didn't need sorting, so I commented the sort function out, but it's always there to be uncommented if you change your mind :)

```js
const arrayObj = [
  { type: 'user', text: 'user1' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user2' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user3' },
  { type: 'clerk', text: 'clerk1' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user4' },
  { type: 'clerk', text: 'clerk2' },
  { type: 'clerk', text: 'clerk3' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user5' },
  { type: 'user', text: 'user6' },
];

const group = ar =>
  ar
    // .sort((a, b) => (a.type < b.type ? -1 : 1))
    .reduce((newAr, obj, i) => {
      if (0 === i) return [[obj]];
      if (obj.type === newAr[newAr.length - 1][0].type)
        return newAr[newAr.length - 1].push(obj), newAr;
      return [...newAr, [obj]];
    }, []);

const groupedAr = group(arrayObj);
console.log(groupedAr);
```

Comment: Nice work with that `reduce`!! I was struggling to construct it, but anyways you got there faster xd

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was thinking, but I didn't have enough knowledge, thank you

Comment: cleaner version of this in the dupe: [Group same elements in JS array, but only when consecutive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53363778/13762301)

Comment: @pilchard I checked the duplicate you mentioned and found the Jordan Soltman user code a little cleaner and basically does what KARASZI István does, do you agree? Sorry about my English

Answer (score 1):

```
function groupConsecutive(arrayObj) {
    if (arrayObj.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    let matchedTypesIndex = 0;
    let newArray = [
        [
             arrayObj[0]
        ]
    ];

    let currentType = arrayObj[0]["type"];
    let i = 1;

    while (i < arrayObj.length) {
        if (arrayObj[i]["type"] === currentType) {
            newArray[matchedTypesIndex].push(arrayObj[i]);
        } else {
            currentType = arrayObj[i]["type"];
            newArray.push([]);
            matchedTypesIndex++;
            newArray[matchedTypesIndex].push(arrayObj[i]);
        }

        i++;
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not best pure solution but works as you need.

```js
var arrayObj = [
    { "type": "user", "text": "user1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user2" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user3" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user4" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk2" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk3" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user5" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user6" }
];

let lastType;
let arr = [];
let arrIndex = -1;

arrayObj.forEach(obj => {
  if(obj.type == lastType) { // add item into last group array by index
    arr[arrIndex].push(obj);
  }
  else { // or add new group array
    lastType = obj.type;
    arrIndex++;
    arr.push([obj]);
  }
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

See This solution it will work

```js
var arrayObj = [
  { type: "user", text: "user1" },
  { type: "user", text: "user2" },
  { type: "user", text: "user3" },
  { type: "clerk", text: "clerk1" },
  { type: "user", text: "user4" },
  { type: "clerk", text: "clerk2" },
  { type: "clerk", text: "clerk3" },
  { type: "user", text: "user5" },
  { type: "user", text: "user6" },
];

let typeNow = arrayObj[0].type;

let res = [];
let resultArray = [];
arrayObj.forEach((obj, i) => {
  if (obj.type == typeNow) {
    resultArray.push(obj);
  } else {
    resultArray = [obj];
    res.push(resultArray);
    typeNow = obj.type;
  }
  if (i == arrayObj.length - 1) res.push(resultArray);
});
console.log(res);
```

This is best solution can i have

It seem **unordred** because of **Browser auto order** but if you try in js file it will work and **ordred**

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding with another way I found to solve my problem. This is just one more way I decided to comment.

**Let's go:** 
I'm traversing the `arrayObjects` array using the appropriate loop for arrays [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and then checking if the variable I set for arrayObjects (`loopArrObj`) has a different value of `type` of the variable (`typeValue`), if it is inserted at the end of the new array (`grouping`) using the array method [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) an empty array and then assign the value of the loopArrObj(Ie, there will be in the array grouping array empty only for the values ​​that are different).

So far so good, we have the first empty array. Next I'm defining this empty array with the push method the loopArrObj object in question, then we get the value through the console. I'm removing 1 from grouping.lengh so the loop assigns from 0 and not 1.

```js
var arrayObjects = [
    { "type": "user", "text": "user1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user2" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user3" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk1" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user4" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk2" },
    { "type": "clerk", "text": "clerk3" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user5" },
    { "type": "user", "text": "user6" }
];

let typeValue,
    grouping = [],
    loopArrObj;

for (loopArrObj of arrayObjects) {

    if (loopArrObj.type !== typeValue) {
        grouping.push([]); 
        typeValue = loopArrObj.type;
    }

    grouping[grouping.length - 1].push(loopArrObj);
}

console.log(grouping);
```